# Passing Interface In Constructor Symfony PHP

Tags: php, symfony, interface, autowired

I'm new to interfaces, could someone please advise when an interface is autowired in a method, since the interface has no functionality, where does the functionality come from in the method $logger->info()  ? thanks

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

public function index(LoggerInterface $logger)
{
    $logger->info('I just got the logger');
    $logger->error('An error occurred');

    $logger->critical('I left the oven on!', [
        // include extra "context" info in your logs
        'cause' => 'in_hurry',
    ]);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Typehinting a function parameter like this means that `$logger` must be an instance of an object that implements `LoggerInterface`. The functionality for your particular `info()` method call will come from whatever concrete class gets passed in -- you could `var_dump($logger)` to find out, but you don't really need to know. All you need to know is that because of the typehinting, you're guaranteed that the variable is an object and that it has an `info()` method.

Comment: The interface gets replaced with a service that implements that interface, and that gets defined by the `services.yaml` or any other bundle configuration. You could also explicitly define different implementation for different consumer services. More info [in this section](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#working-with-interfaces) of the manual.

Comment: Use the Symfony command `bin/console debug:container LoggerInterface` to see all of the services that implement LoggerInterface.  You can then select the first one and it will show a service based on the class `Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger` which implements the LoggerInterface.  Basically the Symfony container allows you to alias an interface to a given implementation.  Might be less confusing if you started with something like the EntityManagerInterface.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Can someone please advise why inject the interface when you could just as well inject the Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Logger concrete class to do the same job? What are the main reasons for injecting an interface? thanks.

Comment: Suppose that Symfony decides to stop using the monolog package and replaces it with a Symfony package.  Something which has happened to other packages.  By using an interface, your application would continue to run as before.  Relying on concrete implementations increases coupling which, in general, is a bad thing.  Not always perhaps and if a class has no interface then you really have no choice if you want autowiring.